# What Design Pattern is separating transform converters

Tags: java, design-patterns

For converting a **Java object model** into **XML** I am using the following design:

For **different types** of objects (e.g. primitive types, collections, null, etc.) I define each its own **converter**, which acts appropriate with respect to the given type. This way it can easily extended without adding code to a huge if-else-then construct.

The converters are chosen by a method which tests whether the object is **convertable** at all and by using a priority ordering. The priority ordering is important so let's say a `List` is not converted by the POJO converter, even though it is convertable as such it would be more appropriate to use the collection converter.

**What design pattern is that?**

I can only think of a similarity to the command pattern.

Comment: Check out the Builder Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can start by trying to categorize the thing you want to do (output an XML file, convert something to something). The design patterns fall into three categories;

- [Structural pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_pattern)
- [Creational pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern)
- [Behavioral pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_pattern)

In this case you have two types of classes, an xml writer and some converters. The xml writer is basically a builder (it *creates* a file)

```
XmlWriter writer = new XmlWriter();
writer.writeHeader();
for (Item item : xmlitems) {
    writer.write(convert(item));
}
writer.close();
```

Now, the actual conversion of a class to xml is done by a few classes. You mention you have a method which tests the classes and directs them to a specific converter. This class can be argued to *create* a new instance of something, so it falls into the creational patterns.

There are three types of patterns that would be suitable IMO.

> - Abstract factory pattern, which provides an interface for creating related or dependent objects without specifying the objects' concrete classes.
> - Builder pattern, which separates the construction of a complex object from its representation so that the same construction process can create different representation.
> - Factory method pattern, which allows a class to defer instantiation to subclasses.
>
> Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern)

Either one is appropriate according to me. The builder pattern is appropriate since the implementation is sort of like

```
public interface Converter {
    void convert(Item item);
    XmlTextNode getResult(); // get xml code
}
```

i.e. you give the class something and you get a result.

The factory pattern is appropriate since you defer instantiation to some other class (your redirect method you spoke of)

```
public XmlTextNode convert(Item item) {
    if (item instanceof ConcreteItem) {
        return new ConcreteConverter(item).getResult();
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid convert type");
}
```

In either case the actual type of the returned item is not important. It depends a little on where you want to "define the pattern". Is it in the method where you switch types, or in the actual creation/converter class.

Then again, I'm no expert in the case.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I also came across [Chain of Responsibility Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ChainOfResponsibilityPattern) even though it's a behavioral pattern and not a creational pattern I think it might apply, too. The different converters could be chained together in an order which reflects the priorites.

Comment: But do you really *chain* the converters? I.e. do each converter call the next converter and so on? I got the impression that you had a top class that created a converter for each class, in a loop.

Comment: The converts are all singletons (at least only created once) and sorted into a list according to their priority. When I convert my Java object model with reflection and iterate recursively through the fields I iterate the converter list and check every time whether a converter can do the conversion and convert then. But I could also chain the converters in that priority order. It would be then a little bit more explicitly with a hierarchy and not with made up priority numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I will go for *Chain of Responsibility* for now, unless someone proves me wrong.

Comment: Okay. As I stated earlier, you don't chain the converters, unless the converters has a "callnext" converter that they call. The Chain of Responsibility is more suitable when handling events for instance, or when there is a set of rules that should be applied to something. But you are free to do as you please.  the patterns is more of a guideline than anything else if you ask me

Comment: I agree with your last sentence. But I could add this method callnext to every converter which is used if the converter is not appropriate and I have a total order over the set of converters.